# how can I fade in and slide a div from onclick with delay

Tags: javascript, function, onclick, fadein

I'm struggling with this javascript as I'm just a designer and would like some help

I have got this code to make it slideIn when I click a button from another page but how can I get it to also fadeIn as it slides In?

This is the site if you want to see it working. If you click on 'portfolio' you will see the slidIn effect with a delay
**[www.jacintodematos.co.uk](http://www.jacintodematos.co.uk)**

```
<script>
     function slideIn(el){
       var elem = document.getElementById(el);
       elem.style.transition = "left 0.5s ease-in 0.8s";
       elem.style.left = "0px";
     }
</script>

<a href="#item3" class="panel" onclick="slideIn('info_text');">PORTFOLIO</a>
```

Comment: Please post your `#info_text` element and it's corresponding CSS.

Comment: sure...<div id="info_text">
               Here you will find all my work throughout my career. You will see different types of media used such as websites, print, logo design and much more...
              </div>

Comment: sure...

<div id="info_text">
               Here you will find all my work throughout my career. You will see different types of media used such as websites, print, logo design and much more...
              </div>

#info_text {
 width: 500px;
 height: 200px;
 position: absolute;
 margin-top: 2%;
 top: 99%;
 left: 400px;
 font-family: Calibri, Verdana, Arial;
 font-size: 18px;
 color: #000;
 float: left;
}

Comment: It's better to edit your quertion and include them there, hard to read in the comments. And check the answer to see whether that's what your'e looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You change the `left` for `transition` to `all` so along with left it'll work for `opacity` too.

I presume the element has a `left` so it's out of the visible window and `opacity` of 0 so we can fade in. Then we just need to change elements opacity to 1.

And finally not sure what you mean by delay, but if you want the whole fadeIn to happen after a specific delay, put it inside `setTimeout`.

```
 function slideIn(el) {
     setTimeout(function () {
         var elem = document.getElementById(el);
         elem.style.transition = "left 2s ease-in-out, opacity 4s linear";
         elem.style.left = "0px";
         elem.style.opacity = 1;
     }, 1000);
 }
```

[**jsfiddle DEMO** (updated)](https://jsfiddle.net/samuraii/yay4qcq5/3/)

**EDIT:**

To control the time use the time parameter in transition:

```
transition: left 2s easi-in-out;
```

`2s` means 2 seconds, if it's too slow make it 1.5s or lower, if it's fast make it 2.5s or 3s or anything.

If you want to have different transitions for different styles separate them with comma:

```
elem.style.transition = "left 2s ease-in-out, opacity 4s linear";
```

`ease-in-out` to have smoother start AND end.

Comment: Edited the code and also the demo. If you find the answer helpful, please vote it up or select it as best answer.